# variable undefined inside inner function

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I have this code that I need to debug, I set break point inside Chrome dev tools, and try to see the value of a variable, but which is inside an inner function, when I try to do that, it's giving me undefined, as shown in the
[image]

So, my understanding is, I should be able to see other values from within inner functions, but the opposite isn't valid, am I missing something here?

Thanks for clarification.

Comment: Please post some code here too.

Comment: I've been noticing this a lot more lately too - I'm guessing it's an optimization they've put in to devtools (or maybe just the engine). It seems like closures that don't get used in your function's scope in the original code aren't available in devtools either. You can choose a higher-level scope in the devtools if you want to just access the variable.

Comment: @JoshfromQaribou Yes, but that doesn't work unless the inner function is being called from the outer function.

Comment: Is it a content script? You'll have to switch context (a dropdown selector above the console, `top` means the webpage) to see its variables.

Comment: @Andrew, if you open the image, the code is there. No need to duplicate what's in the image here too!

Comment: @JoshfromQaribou, I see, but it doesn't make sense to optimize developer tools.. I mean it's for developers to track their code.

Answer (score 0):

Name your inner anonymous functions. This may help the debugger trace the errors.
Example:
Var myfunc = function( mycallback function(){})